# How to pass external variables for function assigned to '$where'

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to use `$where` to compare two fields in a same document. But the condition for comparison is alterable.

For example:

```
let x = 1;
db.test.find({$where: foo});
function foo() {
    return this.a - this.b > x;
}
```

And an error occurs:

```
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

How can I pass this value which is outside the function?

Comment: if that's your exact code, then x should not be "not defined"

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for your comment. This is an example and my code is more complex. Maybe I should try this example first to check the value of x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my question. I use template string here to pass the value of x to the function.

```
let x = 1;
db.test.find(`this.a - this.b > ${x}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a variable and want to use it inside mongoDb function you can do it this way

```
db.test.find({$where: function() {
 let x = 1;
 return this.a - this.b > x;
}})
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The x here actually comes from client and I don't know it's value. Declaring x in mongoDB function may not meet the needs.